# How to show and hide multiple divs by using multiple checkboxes in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How to show and hide divs based on the checkbox checked? I'm using the below code in angular js. I have 3 checkboxes, if one checkbox is clicked the respective div should be shown and the other div should be hidden.

```
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="margin-top: 7px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkSmall" name="small" class="bgCheck" value="small" data-ng-model="ShowSmall" data-ng-change="visibleSmall()" />
    Small Clock
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="margin-top: 7px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkMedium" name="medium" class="bgCheck" value="medium" data-ng-model="ShowMedium" data-ng-change="visibleMedium()" data-ng-init="ShowMedium=true" />
    Medium Clock
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" style="margin-top: 7px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkBig" name="big" class="bgCheck" value="big" data-ng-model="ShowBig" data-ng-change="visibleBig()" />
    Large Clock
  </label>
  <div data-ng-show="ShowSmall">
    Small Clock
  </div>
  <div data-ng-show="ShowMedium">
    Medium Clock
  </div>
  <div data-ng-show="ShowLarge">
    Large... or Big Clock?
  </div>
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear....which div to hide/show on which check box checked/unchecked?

Comment: please see below fiddle, i need to show div's based on checkbox clicked

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szong04w/2/)

We can use `ng-show` and put a truthy / falsy value inside, so the DOM element with that attribute will be shown / hidden depending on that variable.

```
  <div data-ng-show="ShowSmall && !ShowMedium && !ShowLarge">
    Small Clock
  </div>
```

When `ShowSmall` is true and the other two is false, that `<div>` will be shown.  Try interact with the Fiddle to see if that fits your needs!

You may also want to checkout [NgIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) which instead of hiding, it removes the DOM element from the DOM tree.

Side note: If you only wants one to be shown, you may consider using radio buttons instead of checkboxes. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szong04w/3/)

Comment: how to hide and show those dive based on checkbox clicked

Comment: @PK-1825 The original answer makes every checkbox and div independent.  Still we can use condition to make others hidden.  If you want only 1 to be selected, you may want to use radio buttons (please check the last sentence of edited answer)